# Review: Add most common comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, comments

As a 500+ reputation user, I have been reviewing First Posts and Late Answers.

The more I review, the more I see similar situations, such as:

1. **A user posts an answer with only a link** and in this case I add a comment referring the user to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and suggest the user to improve his answer.
2. **A user posts an answer that is really a comment to another answer**. In this case I add a comment similar indicating that the user can comment everywhere when he has enough reputation (with the relevant links to the Help Center).
3. **A user posts an answer asking the OP if he ever solved his issue, because he has the same problem**. In this case I add a comment similar to *This does not answer the question. When you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you can place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) so the question gains more attention.*
4. **A user posts an answer with only code**. In this case I add a comment suggesting the user to add a description of what the problem was and how does his answer solves that problem.

There are many more cases involving both answers and questions and I see that many users have default comments for this common cases (I also do, in a text file).

I know it's a long shot, but I would like to request a feature that would allow me to add this common comments within Stack Overflow and I could use those comments when reviewing. Something like:

1. A select box would appear only to users with 500+ reputation.
2. This select box may appear only when reviewing.
3. This select box would have my common comments. I could add another comment with an icon next to the select box.
4. When the user selects an option of the select box, the text would automatically appear inside the text box (where you could still edit and adjust as you like).

What are your thoughts on this?

<sub>Just in case you suggest that you should flag 2) and 3), I also do that.</sub>

Comment: Biggest problem with reviewing is users *robo-reviewing*, racing through the review queue without actually paying much attention to the posts.  You are asking for robo-comments, that ought to make the problem worse.

Comment: @milz Cases 1-4 are usually handled by [Low Quality Posts Queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391), where they get auto-comments based on reviewer's actions(Delete reason).

Comment: So you are saying that having a way to quickly add comments is worse because users would be more prone to add comments that may not be valid? I didn't thought about that case, but I would say that if you add a comment you try to be the most accurate possible. Of course, it all depends of who's reviewing.

Comment: @HansPassant First posts queue is usually being taken very lightheartedly, most posts just get [robo "No action needed"](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/223339/total-and-noactionneeded-firstposts-reviews) and continue to live on, when they should have been flagged(closed), downvoted or at least given a recommendation comment. So auto-comments in that queue won't make it worse, because those who don't care won't use it (that is two click, and "OK" is only one), while those who care may be relieved from abusing their keyboards with generic replies.

Comment: I don't think the social implications of "canned comments" would be mostly positive. It looks like a flag to me...

Comment: @HansPassant I think you got it exactly the other way around: motivated users want to do good work in the queue, but after the 1000th "please provide the error message" or "format your code" the human brain just can't keep up the same level of quality (it is studied quite well for air traffic controllers). The second and to me much more acute point is the differing wording. Not only for non-native speakers, it would be advisable to once create some good texts in the hive mind and then use them, when appropriate.

Comment: https://github.com/stephenostermiller/stack-exchange-comment-templates ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a user script called "AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE" that can be installed as a Chrome or Firefox browser extension.

This extension provides a few default comments and allows the user to add custom texts. This at least lets me achieve this on a per-user, per-machine basis, although it doesn't address the need for such functionality for all users by default.

For more information, visit [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: Isn't this just a dirty workaround for an obvious problem?

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis yes, most of the tools the community has built to work around this aging neglected system are.