# Convenient addressing 'images of code' and other common mistakes in review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

I often review the Triage queue and there are questions that contain images of code which is discouraged (and I agree with that of course). Many of the questions / answers in the other queues have this problem too.

There is a good explanation for beginners: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

However, when I want to bring that to the OP, it takes some time for me to find that link, open it and copy the formatted comment with link (`[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)`)

Of course bookmarking can save some time but it should be done by every user and on every device / browser they are using. And you still need to open it which takes additional time and may be annoying if you make a lot of reviews.

This scenario is applicable to other common mistakes ("Images of code" just seems the most annoying one).

**I think the following feature would be useful:**

I believe it makes sense to include common comment templates ("please don't post images of code", "please add debugging details", "write in English", etc. below the comment form in review queues.

It would save a lot of time to reviewers, make the review process less annoying and allow for more thorough reviews (since it there would be less need to be distracted by looking for canonical comments).

Here is the example of where it could be included (only for comments in the review queues):

[image: Comment form]

There could be a few buttons that add a template of answer to the comment form, so the reviewer could add more info if needed and then publish it.

**Update.** There was [a discussion on Meta 8 years ago on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270914/review-add-most-common-comments) the currently accepted answer is to propose to use SE-AutoReviewComments, [a community-developed browser extension](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments). However, this in not a resolution, it is just a workaround which still needs to be applied by each user individually + on each device.

It is not much different from bookmarking 'favorite' explanation and it is a kind of inconvenience that I propose to avoid.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270914/review-add-most-common-comments among others. The SOCVR chatroom does maintain a list with common comments to be used with the AutoReviewComments userscript: https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts#endorsed-scripts

Comment: This feature exists in the form of the dedicated close/flag reasons. Use them.

Comment: @CodyGray the flag is definitely not the same as comment as it is (i) does not provide a quick feedback and (ii) is not a personalized form of feedback and is treated differently therefore. I want to be able to write a custom message to OP.

Comment: @rene Thanks! That question is actually very similar to mine but in my opinion it is inappropriately marked as resolved. There is no resolution, just a workaround which still needs to be applied by each user individually + on each device. It is a kind of inconvenience that I propose to avoid.

Comment: If you want to write a custom message, then *write a custom message*. You are asking for exactly the opposite of a custom message here: you are asking for a canned template. The canned templates are the close/flag reasons. Those definitely "provide a quick feedback". **But you did nail it with "is treated differently". The difference is that you don't get to bypass the consensus process. Which is the whole point and exactly why you should use the standard reasons.** If you misjudged whether the question is appropriate, then you shouldn't be leaving incorrect and confusing advice.

Comment: *"However, I see the marking of the question as resolved as non-reasonable..."* Nobody marked either this question or the other, older one you linked as resolved.

Comment: @CodyGray This question is marked as resolved https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270914/review-add-most-common-comments

Comment: @CodyGray in what way the flag provides a quick feedback to the OP? A comment is visible right after publishing, a flag should be approved by a mod first.
Regarding "treating differently": I meant treating differently by the OP. A polite, friendly comment from a real person is definitely treated much better by those who ask than something 'robotic'. I do not mean flags / consensus are not needed but they cannot serve the same purpose of explaining something in a friendly way. And I want to make this easier.

Comment: That question you linked is not marked as resolved... There's no [status-*] tag on it, nor has it had any other status (e.g., obsolete) attached to it (so no banners being displayed). If it were resolved, it would have a [[meta-tag:status-completed]] tag on it. No, flags recommending closure of a question don't need to be approved by mods. The flag reason is supposed to be friendly and polite. If it isn't, then it needs to be fixed. Why would the flag reason be any less friendly and polite than a canned comment that you would post? I don't understand how this makes sense.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for quick response. That question has an accepted answer so it can be understood as resolved by at least many people in the community (I wouldn't like to continue the terminology debate). Regarding "canned comments": I propose templates to comments that can be extended when needed (I would certainly do that). The flag reason is certainly less friendly because you do not see the user who wants you to fix the question and whom to appeal. And I would not recommend closure all questions with images of code straight off, I would ask the OP to fix them first.

Comment: @dimnnv "*That question has an accepted answer so it can be understood as resolved by at least many people in the community*" and all those people will be wrong. Sorry, not really much we can do there. Acceptance is just incorrect. And people building up completely fictitious narratives around acceptance are also an issue.

Comment: "is not a personalized form of feedback" Canned comments aren’t either, are they?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It is better in the following sense: you see who is posting the comment and you can discuss it right there it if you do not agree. But again, I am supporting the idea that extending the 'default' answer templates should be encouraged.

Comment: Canned comments such as "Please do not upload images of code/data/errors." really aren’t as helpful as they may seem -critically, they aren’t actionable at all. Making them immediately useful will need significantly more than the tiny bit from the can. Would such almost-useless stubs really simplify comment writing in a significant way?

Comment: I have edited the accepted answer on that linked question to clarify that it is a per-user workaround rather than a solution/official response to the question that somehow "resolves" it for all users.

Comment: @CodyGray "The canned templates are the close/flag reasons." From personal experience (and from what I can tell, this aligns with most other regular curators) **many more** canned templates are necessary to communicate with OPs than what the close reasons offer. There is no way to get the system to display a message that tells OP not to post code as an image, for example. Further, we can't show such messages to OP directly; only when three votes are cast or by triggering the Community bot.

Comment: @VLAZ "and all those people will be wrong. Sorry, not really much we can do there. Acceptance is just incorrect. And people building up completely fictitious narratives around acceptance are also an issue" At some point, UI designers (such as Stack Exchange's) need to accept that if everyone interprets the site's output a certain way (e.g. checkmark next to an "answer" to a "question" = the "question" was "resolved"), *that's the fault of the UI, not collectively of the countless individuals using it*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "critically, they aren’t actionable at all." - I don't see your point of view. This is fixed by phrasing the message appropriately and including a link to the corresponding Meta Q&A.

Comment: @Karl What do you mean, "There is no way to get the system to display a message…not to post code as an image"? This is exactly what the "needs debugging details" reason tells them. That you cannot, as an individual, show system messages to the OP directly is a feature, not a limitation. If you want to tell a user something based on your personal feelings, then you can type a comment and write pretty much anything you want. However, if you are trying to communicate official policy, you (as an individual user) aren't an official policy-maker, and you could be mistaken, so consensus is required.

Comment: "This is exactly what the "needs debugging details" reason tells them." **No, it does not**. That's the problem. Please see the answer I just posted for details. "However, if you are trying to communicate official policy, you (as an individual user) aren't an official policy-maker, and you could be mistaken, so consensus is required." You know very well, as a moderator, that there are many more points of official policy related to closure of questions, than there are closure reasons.

Answer (score 9):

This *could* be useful but it really hinges on whether we can establish a process for maintaining high quality comments.

At the moment, many "common comments" are actually terrible at helping posters. Many are cargo cult of misunderstood rules, such as "you must show an attempt". Others seem helpful if you already know what to do, yet are devoid of concrete, actionable advice - the "[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)" is a prime example that hides some vague advice behind tons of generic infodump.
Frankly, we shouldn’t make it easier to post such comments.

So before having a magic button to paste canned comments, we should discuss what those comments actually are. How are they proposed or selected? How are they updated, or are they updated at all? How do we ensure people add specific details to the comments, or is this not even the goal? How do we provide guidance, or must the comments be self-evident to commenters as well?

Comment: This. So much this. Also, once we finish establishing what the canned comments are, we still shouldn't make them canned comments. We should build them into the system as flag reasons, or at least some kind of temporary annotation that can be added to posts, not comments.

Comment: I really fail to see how your prime example is a prime example. Not uploading images of text, and linking to that, is extremely clear, and is likely the most useful canned comment that can be provided. What am I missing?

Comment: @CodyGray It currently takes 3 people with 3k+ reputation to close a question. Perhaps the right solution is some form of a drop-down list in which one can specifically select exactly the problems (such as images of code), and thereby only requiring 1 or 2 people to close for this? The problem will be the cases where «needs debugging details» or «unclear» capture more than just those specific reasons.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship It is extremely clear what not to do, which isn’t helpful once it is already done. It is not at all clear *what to do instead*. The implied action of "Don’t post X” is "delete X" - which won’t fix the problem. In many cases, even the next step of "post X as Y instead" won’t  fix the problem. What we actually want is an MRE. The canned comment is several steps away from saying that.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship it needs to say what to do, instead of what not to do. Humans are bad at processing negation in the first place, and also the alternatives are not immediately apparent. Aside from that, more work needs to be done - "post code as text" doesn't directly imply "post code as properly formatted text", which in turn requires a link to the formatting help; and then there is the question of which code to post. (It is practically never the case that someone goes to the effort to make a proper MRE, then screenshots it.)

Comment: Anyway, despite our prior friction, this is an excellent synthesis.

Answer (score 3):

This need *is* already addressed by the system, actually (at least for questions. I don't know if the Triage queue covers answers, too): the "lacks Minimal Reproducible Example" close reason. From the Triage review queue, you can apply this flag or close vote with the following steps:

1. Select the Flag option and click Submit:

   [image: Screenshot of the Flag option selected in the Triage review queue, with a red underline]
2. Select the "Needs improvement" option

   [image: Screenshot of the flagging reasons window, with Needs Improvement option underlined in red]
3. Select the "a community-specific reason"

   [image: Screenshot of the close vote reasons window with the community-specific reason underlined in red]
4. Select the "Needs debugging details" close/flag option and click the Vote/Flag button at the bottom of the window

   [image: Screenshot of the Needs debugging details option selected in the close/flag window]

Code and error messages on Stack Overflow need to be included in text format. Any post including code or error messages in image format only is in violation of the site rules for asking about existing code or about debugging issues. This is explained at the very beginning of the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page in the Help Center:

> When asking a debugging question, people will be better able to provide help if you [provide code *as text*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) **in your question** that prospective answerers can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

And then again in the "Complete" section of the same page:

> Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included as text in the question itself:
>
> - [**DO NOT** use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

The link to the MRE help center page is included in the closure banner of questions closed for that reason:

[image: Screenshot of part of the "closed question" banner that appears on top of the question--it shows the status message of the question (that it is closed) and the action needed to reopen it (edit the question to include a minimal reproducible example)]

Comment: 4 clicks through an unintuitive interface ... I honestly would never have thought to select "flag" here. But i don't work this particular queue so maybe it's more intuitive for people who do. But still 4 clicks is a lot for "common" close reasons.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution.  First of all, it requires three users to vote to close the question, then another three users (or the same ones) to vote to reopen it after it's fixed.  All when one user could tell the OP to fix it in a comment and save everyone all that trouble.  It also requires the user to read through that entire help page and understand that that was the specific issue.

Comment: @RyanM I used to leave comments for this instead of close voting. And then I took a Cody to the knee.

Comment: @user You can also cast a close vote at the same time (I'm not suggesting you shouldn't), but it's always better if a quick edit from the asker makes closure unnecessary (at which point it can be retracted and no more need to be cast).

Comment: While we're living in fantasy worlds, @RyanM, why not just have the asker provide the required information in the expected format when they publish the question? Obviously, if the close voter/flagger can fix the problems with the question in lieu of casting a flag/vote, they should do so. But if the fix can only come from the author of the question, then they should do exactly what Tyler suggests. Although Roddy's point is ever-so-valid. The UI is terrible. At least this one has spaces between sentences...

Comment: Aside from this UI being terrible, it's part of the queue system - which as I've explained countless times, has poor discoverability and even worse incentive structure.

Comment: "the "lacks Minimal Reproducible Example" close reason." Okay, so *after* three people have correctly voted to close the question as lacking debugging details (which requires them to understand policy well enough to interpret image of code -> the information content of this image effectively doesn't exist -> therefore there is no MRE), or lower-rep users flag it and eventually a mod responds to the flag (or it goes into a close-vote review queue to get the three close votes).... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) after all of that, some AI examines the question, deduces that the reason the question lacks debugging details is because an image of the code was posted instead of actual properly formatted code, and shows a custom message to the user that links them to the [corresponding FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) with a one-sentence summary of the specific applicable policy. How conv- oh, wait, it **doesn't** do that? Well, perhaps now it is a little clearer what this Meta question is asking for.

Comment: That is: our hypothetical image-posting OP on the main site still has to go through multiple clicks to get to the relevant information, after reading through policy to figure out specifically which guideline was not properly followed - and the first link in this chain isn't labelled in a remotely suggestive way. If I posted an image of code and am given a message about "shortest code necessary", *why should I infer that the problem is the formatting, rather than the contents*?

Comment: It's not really part of the queue system. Flags and close votes can be cast independently of any queues. And mods don't handle these flags. Neither do AIs. It doesn't link them to a community-curated FAQ because we have [an official Help Center article](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we link to instead. You'll note the *very first sentence* of that article: "…provide code as text in your question…" with italic, bold, and hyperlink formatting that makes it highly visible. Oh yeah, and…that *does* link to the community-curated FAQ. Seems we *do* have exactly this.

Comment: @CodyGray It honestly feels to me as if you are going out of your way to misunderstand what I have already explained very carefully. "You'll note the very first sentence of that article: "…provide code as text in your question…" with italic, bold, and hyperlink formatting that makes it highly visible." It is not, in fact, highly visible. You had to draw my attention to it in order for me to realize it was there, and then it took deliberate reading (not scanning) effort on my part to confirm that, even though I knew what to look for and even though I had separately, recently looked at the page.

Comment: The AI part of my comment was satirical - the point is that the close box message doesn't say that; it links and then expects the user to read clearly and comprehend a more detailed text, instead of directly being given a summary of the most common actual issues.

Comment: @CodyGray *"why not just have the asker provide the required information in the expected format when they publish the question?"* [Well, I've suggested that, too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424646/208273).  Anyway, my point is that informing the OP of the problem would be a helpful _addition_ to flagging/voting to close, not a replacement.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yeah the UI isn't great, which is one reason why I don't frequent that queue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great feature I would love to see. Currently, I have a text file with a bunch of comment templates that I simply copy/paste when needed. However this takes time, as I need to open the file, find the right template, and copy/paste it. I understand there are browser extensions and userscripts, but I would prefer a feature built into the site. If it was built in, I could spend less time getting the template and more time <s>bullying and harassing</s> **assisting** new users with the rules of the site.

If implemented, it would be nice if you could add your own templates that you use often.

Comment: I have a text file too but it's permanently open in Notepad++ so always quickly to hand. Currently it has about 30 canned comments of which about 10 get regular use.

Comment: [Macro keyboards](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/category/macro-keyboards/) / [macro pads](https://keyboardsexpert.com/macropad-mechanical-keyboard-faqs/) are great for this sort of thing. Though you may soon run out of keys and the typeout rate is [limited to 25 characters per second](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/06/27/blues-typing-out-fixed-texts-on-both-qmk-and-arduino-leonardo-based-macro-keyboards/) (for instance, [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/faq_general?id=what-is-qmk)'s default key delay is 20 ms, probably for good reason).

Comment: Improving your typing speed is also great for this sort of thing. I don't use canned comments; I type them out each time. Although I don't achieve 1500 wpm, unfortunately.

Comment: @CodyGray "I don't use canned comments; I type them out each time." - and *what exactly do you gain by this*?

Comment: Being able (i.e., *forced*) to say something custom and situation-specific, @Karl. If I don't have anything beyond what the system message says, I use the system message.

Comment: @CodyGray I don’t use any userscripts, so I don’t have canned comments at hand. I find this to be a limitation. The system doesn’t provide specific and exact reasons to choose (for flagging), so providing something more specific (yet canned (because it’s so common)) in a comment, is useful. It also signals that I am available for elaborating. Most posters aren’t interested in an elaboration, so I most often don’t care to invest my time in doing so unless they’re actually willing to listen to me.

Comment: (I could use some other non-userscript-solution, but there’s too much work involved, for multiple browsers, for multiple platforms). So yes, I do agree with building these things into the system.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, of course, with the need of some sort of automation while reviewing content. I use a free utility, an intelligent macro editor with custom hotkeys. I share many feedbacks just typing  `>imgs` , obtaining this:

> Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417). Thank you

or `>minimal` for:

> Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

while still having the option to insert other text, such as `Welcome on Stack Overflow, >minimal`
In short, I prefer to slightly adjust every feedback I give, adding some context, giving to the new user a more "human" approach.

Answer (score 1):

At the **absolute very least**, this guidance:

[image: TylerH's screen capture of "needs debugging details" closure guidance]

**needs to** include wording **right there** about the necessity to post code as properly formatted text, not an image. It should link both to the [corresponding meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) and to the [help page about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Anything less is a UX failure, plain and simple. Imagine being a new user: you have posted your code as an image, and then people close it with this message. Are you going to deduce "oh, I should have copied and pasted the text of my code instead, with proper formatting"? **How**? Only if you

- notice that the slightly-differently-shaded text is clickable
- *don't* come to an obvious-but-wrong conclusion from the text that's already there, such as:

  - "Oh, maybe I should get an image of a different part of the code instead, or more of the code"
  - "Oh, maybe I should explain the requirement more clearly"
  - "Oh, maybe I should explain the problem more clearly"
- actually read the link
- somehow conclude that the summary at the top hasn't adequately explained the issue to you, and thus keep scrolling (because you have already had the point explained as "Complete: Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself", there is *no reason to suspect* that the image is a problem, and at this point you have already received what appears to be a complete, coherent explanation)
- ... all the way to the "Complete" section

*Why put people through that, and take the extremely large risk of them not actually going through it*, when we could **just say up front** to post code as properly formatted text, not an image?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because there's a limit on how much of that linked Help Center article that we can put into the message that is displayed inline, and although in some cases it is most relevant to mention posting code as formatted text rather than an image, there are plenty of other things that also can and do go wrong with questions, all of which are covered in the linked Help Center article but cannot reasonably be covered in that inline guidance message. If someone who has their question closed isn't interested in reading *one single article* they're linked to, that's not a UX failure.

Comment: Also, if we want to talk about UX and guidance, the place to put the advice to post code as an image isn't after the horse has already left the barn. It's in the place where people write the question in the first place, not messages that get displayed after it's already been closed. Last I checked, we do do that, although I don't know if maybe it's been broken recently with all the churn.

Comment: Wouldn’t this be majorly confusing to people who did not post images? Are you proposing a close text that can be adjusted to the specific shortcomings of a question?

Comment: @CodyGray [Please feel free to put a freehand red circle around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2wDy.png) the part that specifically tells people that code should be text rather than an image. I don't think this has changed at all recently, either. As far as I can tell, the closest you get, and the closest you've gotten for years, is that expanding the "show some code" section gives you a link to the MRE help page.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no more so than the current message - which already proposes three different things that might be wrong - is to people who didn't get all three of them wrong.

Comment: " because there's a limit on how much of that linked Help Center article that we can put into the message that is displayed inline" - does this fit? `Edit the question and make sure it includes a [proper minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - showing code as [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text, [not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) - and explain the expected vs. actual result of that example.` The "This will help others answer the question." part is wasting space, FWIW.